# Jboss Wildfly 8.1.0 cutting last 200 lines of my HTML

Tags: java, html, jboss, wildfly

help please. I can't figure out why wildfly is cutting of last ~200 lines of my html pages.

I have this application which I've migrated from resin to wildfly. Everything works fine on resin but if I run it on wildfly pages are not complete.

I have this testing page:

```
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin sit amet eleifend metus. Fusce consectetur arcu dignissim mauris consequat, quis condimentum lorem ornare. Ut eget nisi enim. Proin cursus, erat id lobortis tempus, nibh odio vestibulum justo, ac mattis nibh tortor at nisl. Nunc condimentum felis id dapibus faucibus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed id ipsum ligula. Ut eu mauris in elit blandit iaculis at a risus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris faucibus, ipsum sed cursus posuere, diam dui egestas tellus, a lacinia quam velit et quam. Vestibulum interdum neque quis augue finibus blandit. Sed at tellus quis risus posuere luctus et ut nunc. Nunc vel neque non urna rutrum elementum suscipit quis tellus. Phasellus vulputate tristique orci sit amet ultrices. Pellentesque risus ligula, posuere nec semper sollicitudin, suscipit non velit. Donec ut diam justo.
</p>
<p>
    Suspendisse tempus blandit risus, sed scelerisque arcu tempor vel. Pellentesque tempus tellus lacinia, tincidunt mauris sed, elementum purus. Proin consequat massa magna, vel vestibulum neque rutrum sit amet. Ut nibh elit, mollis a congue id, laoreet pharetra orci. Etiam eleifend scelerisque diam auctor euismod. Nulla magna massa, pharetra vitae tellus quis, rutrum dapibus purus. Maecenas vestibulum eget risus id efficitur. Morbi bibendum justo id dolor bibendum, sed ornare mi imperdiet. Etiam a ultricies massa, ut dapibus elit. Etiam justo lacus, sodales a sollicitudin ac, pellentesque facilisis quam. Aenean facilisis placerat dolor, a tempor est porta eget. Donec ac mauris non orci scelerisque vulputate non quis ligula. Maecenas ut mauris quis metus convallis auctor. Suspendisse vitae elementum nunc, vel egestas nunc. Donec in tempus ante. Donec dictum vitae eros a ullamcorper.
</p>
```

It does not really matter how long is the page (I've tried 300 lines, 1500 lines) and always it's missing ~200 last lines.

I guess I've missed some config or something.

JSPs are ok. Only HTML has this issue.

Any ideas???

Comment: Did you try WildFly 8.2.0?

Comment: Does the Content-Length header in the response match the length of the original or the truncated content?

Comment: I have this problem in Wildfly 8.2.0 when deploying a clojure app to it and I've confirmed it's a problem with the content-length header. Since I'm proxying requests I can remove the content-length from the response and everything displays fine. Unfortunately I don't know enough about Wildfly yet to determine how to resolve this without hacking apart the headers. Hopefully someone who knows a bit more will pick this up since it's the second item in Google's search results.